# Java shared folder synchronization between clusters

Tags: java, synchronization

There is a small task for cluster synchronization, part of which is that there will be a certain shared folder with several files that can be changed. Which solution will be the most simple and lightweight? Considering that there are not so many files (5-10) and they will not change too often?

It is assumed that there will be one folder (for example, in cloud storage), a link to which all parts of the cluster will have. This folder will contain files that can be read or modified by any of the participants. It is necessary that at any time it was possible to determine that a file was in the process of being modified in order to prevent conflicts.

I already thought about synchronizing with file locks or H2, I don’t want to pull third-party libraries for this, but this is acceptable if they are small and suitable for this issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "synchronization"? Can *any* copy of the folder change, or is there a central "main" copy that ever other one should be an exact copy of? Is there already code of yours running on each of those systems? Do they already communicate? Do you need changes to be synchronized immediately or is simply copying them over every few hours sufficient?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sorry, I didn’t describe the task accurately enough. None of the options are currently implemented. It is assumed that there will be one folder (for example, in cloud storage), a link to which all parts of the cluster will have. This folder will contain files that can be read or modified by any of the participants. It is necessary that at any time
it was possible to determine that a file was in the process of being modified in order to prevent conflicts.

Comment: Please update your question to add those details so others can see them without having to read through all comments. That sounds rather involved and I don't think implementing that from scratch is the correct approach, even if the amount of files and data size isn't too big. The problem is probably not data size, but complexity of getting this right. I'd look for third-party libraries primarily (no, I don't have a specific one in mind).